# Prevent duplicate content - spin it?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, content

I am building some mini-blogs with related content.  These are designed to build good links to my main page. I don't have the time or energy to write 10's of unique articles a week. I understand my suggestion might be against Google's policies, but I was wondering if the following would be possible:

Take a article, randomize the paragraphs and sentences inside of the paragraphs, then replace some words with synonyms.

Would this prevent the articles going into the duplicate content filter?

Comment: Doesn't this suggest plagiarism to you?

Comment: Let me be more clear. Myself writing 1 good organic article, and then spinning it into 5-6 unique articles.

Comment: Do we have a tag "turd polishing"?

Comment: all content is relative. lol

Answer (score 4):

1. This would be low quality content which is exactly what the Panda algorithm is looking to weed out.
2. Making minor changes to content won't fool Google for long if at all. Switching paragraphs around is still the same content and Google knows about synonyms.
3. Unless the content is made available you'll be violating copyrights of the authors. That is immoral and, if you are reported, may cause your site to manually reviewed and almost certainly dropped by Google (yes, they do manual reviews of websites. In fact [Matt Cutts recently confirmed as much at Hacker News](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-ban-cutts-support-14164.html)).

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to build 1 terrific article or website, which generates organic links by itself (i.e. other blogs linking to your fabulous piece of writing or website), than create 10 spun articles and link to your page. It might fly under the radar of the duplicate content filter, but it's mostly bad quality content. Put your effort in your main article instead of generating rubbish content.

There are many article spinners to be found on the net, in case you're really convinced that's the way your link building strategy should be.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this prevent the articles going into the duplicate content
>   filter?

Instead of asking "is this spam?" perhaps you should be asking whether it will get the results you want.

If you are only concerned with *having* content on your mini-sites, then yes you can randomly generate whatever you want.

If you want content that is intelligible to to humans, this method will fail.

If you want content the humans might consider linking to, hire a writer.

If you want to improve rankings and traffic to the main site you've created mini-sites to link to ... perhaps you should devote your energies to work on that main site.